# Copy over a large number of files with new names

Tags: command-line, server, bash, python, cp

I have a large number of files (tens of thousands) I need to copy over from /dir1 to /dir2  but the name of the file must change as such:

**OLD NAME** ---> **NEW NAME**

filename.txt ---> bob_filename_1253.txt

Where bob is the uid that owns the file and 1253 is the last time it was modified.

I am currently achieving this with a python script that loops through every file and then cp's it to the new destination, creating the new file name through string slicing.

HOWEVER, this is taking a torturous amount of time. Is there a cleaner, faster way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If bulk copying to the new directory and then renaming is an option, then the Perl-based `rename` command might be an option - however it's hard to say whether that might be faster without seeing your python script.

Answer (score 0):

The following script should get the job done. Try it and when you are satisfied with the results, remove the comment `#` in front of `cp -p "$oldpath""$f9" "$newpath""$new"` to do the actual job.

The script will create a file in your home directory called `ls_file.txt`. This file is needed to store the output of the `ls -l "$oldpath"` command and the script will need to read from it during execution. **After the script finishes executing**, the `ls_file.txt` file is no longer needed and you can delete it.

## Always back up

To create and use the script file, please follow these steps:

1. Create and edit the script file in your home directory by running the following command in the terminal:

   `nano ~/my_script.sh`
2. Copy and paste the following code into the editor changing `/full/path/to/old/directory/` with the full path to your `/dir1` directory and `/full/path/to/new/directory/` to the full path to your `/dir2` directory:

```
#!/bin/bash

oldpath="/full/path/to/old/directory/"
newpath="/full/path/to/new/directory/"

ls -l "$oldpath" > "ls_file.txt"

while read f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7 f8 f9
                do
                        mod="${f6}${f7}${f8}"
                        mod2=$(echo "$mod" | tr -d ' :')
                        name="${f9%.*}"
                        ext="${f9##*.}"
                        new="$f3""_""$name""_""$mod2"".""$ext"
                        echo "$f9"" ---> Will be renamed ---> ""$new"
                        echo "----------------------------"
#                       cp -p "$oldpath""$f9" "$newpath""$new"
                done < "ls_file.txt"
```

3. Save the script file and exit the editor by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> then press <kbd>Y</kbd>.
4. Make the script file executable by running the following command in the terminal:

   `chmod +x ~/my_script.sh`
5. Run the script by running the following command in the terminal:

   `bash ~/my_script.sh`

Done

---

**How it works?**

Running the script from my home directory on a test directory `dir1/` which contains one file `file.txt` and a test directory `dir2/` which is empty while specifying `oldpath="/home/raffa/test/dir1/"` and `newpath="/home/raffa/test/dir2/"`, the following process is an example of how the script works:

1. The command `ls -l /home/raffa/test/dir1/` is executed and the output is written to a file named `ls_file.txt` which will then contain the attributes and the names of the files in `dir1/` in this case one file `file.txt` like so:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 raffa raffa 0 Jan 25 19:49 file.txt
```

- `-rw-r--r--` is the file mode.
- `1` is the number of links.
- The first `raffa` is the name of the owner.
- The second `raffa` is the name of the group.
- `0` is the file size.
- `Jan 25 19:49` **(three fields)** is the date and time of the last modification.
- `file.txt` is the name of the file.

.
 2. The script will read the contents of `dir1/` from `ls_file.txt` line by line and split each line into fields (nine in total) and assign the value of each field to a variable `f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7 f8 f9`.

3. `mod="${f6}${f7}${f8}"` will assign the last modification date and time stored in the variables `f6 f7 f8` to the variable `mod` so it will contain a value like so:

```
Jan2519:49
```

4. `mod2=$(echo "$mod" | tr -d ' :')` will take the value of the variable `$mod`, delete any spaces and colons `:` and assign it to the variable `mod2` so it will contain a value like so:

```
Jan251949
```

5. `name="${f9%.*}"` will assign the file name without the extension to the variable `name` so it will contain a value like so:

```
file
```

6. `ext="${f9##*.}"` will assign the file extension without the name to the variable `ext` so it will contain a value like so:

```
txt
```

7. `new="$f3""_""$name""_""$mod2"".""$ext"` will format the new file name as `owner_name_lastmodified.extension` and assign it to the variable `new` so it will contain a value like so:

```
raffa_file_Jan251949.txt
```

8. `cp -p "$oldpath""$f9" "$newpath""$new"` will copy the original file `file.txt` from `dir1/` to `dir2/` renaming it to `raffa_file_Jan251949.txt` and will try to preserve the original attributes of the file during this process, so it will execute like so:

```
cp -p /home/raffa/test/dir1/file.txt /home/raffa/test/dir2/raffa_file_Jan251949.txt
```

This process will be repeated for all the files in `dir1/` with any extension.

---

**Another time format:**

If you prefer the last modification date and time format to be like this `20200125133815` where `2020` is the year and `01` is the month and `25` is the day and `13` is the hour in 24 format and `38` is the minutes and `15` is the seconds so your copied filenames will look like this `raffa_file_20200125133815.txt`, then please replace the script code above with the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

oldpath="/full/path/to/old/directory/"
newpath="/full/path/to/new/directory/"


ls -l --time-style="+%Y%m%d%H%M%S" "$oldpath" > "ls_file.txt"

while read f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7
                do
                        mod="${f6}"
                        name="${f7%.*}"
                        ext="${f7##*.}"
                        new="$f3""_""$name""_""$mod"".""$ext"
                        echo "$f7"" ---> Will be renamed ---> ""$new"
                        echo "----------------------------"
#                       cp -p "$oldpath""$f7" "$newpath""$new"
                done < "ls_file.txt"
```

---

**Notice:**

In some cases [parsing the output of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) might be better avoided.

Comment: Thank you so much for this incredibly in depth response. It turns out this approach takes a similar amount of time to what I was doing before but it was certainly helpful in order to better understand how I can achieve this with a shell script as opposed to python!

Comment: @Javier You are most welcome. As far as speed goes, I am afraid this is as fast as you can get on the software side. The real limit is the speed of your HDD. To get more speed you will need to replace your HDD with an SSD if your system supports it. Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are starting with an empty `dir2` so that you can copy the files from `dir1` to `dir2` without conflict and **then** rename them, I'd try something like this:

```
printf '%s\0' dir1/*.txt | xargs -r0 cp -np -t dir2/
```

to perform the copy, then

```
cd dir2/

printf '%s\0' *.txt | xargs -r0 rename -n -- '
  $_ = join "_", ( getpwuid( (stat $_)[4] ) )[0], $_, (stat $_)[9]
'
```

to rename (remove the `-n` from the `rename` command once you are happy with the proposed changes).

---

Although it's most often used for simple `s/pattern/replacement/` name changes, the Perl-based `rename` command available in current versions of Ubuntu can actually rename files based on pretty much arbitrary Perl expressions.

In this case we can use Perl's built in `stat` to get the numeric UID and mtime, and then use `getpwuid` to turn the UID to a username. `(stat $_)[9]` is the modification time (mtime) in epoch seconds - if you need it in another format you can use `POSIX::strftime` or one of several other time manipulation modules.

Answer (score 0):

**Copying `*.txt` files with renaming from `dir1/` to `dir2/` directory:**

```
$ ls -l
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user 4096 лют 19 01:06 dir1
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user 4096 лют 19 01:08 dir2

$ ls dir1
name1.txt  name2.txt  name3.txt
```

```
$ for filepath in ./dir1/*; 
    do username=$(stat -c '%U' $filepath) && 
       filedate=$(stat -c '%Y' $filepath) && 
       newpartname='dir2/'$n'_'"${filepath//'./dir1/'}" && 
       cp $filepath "${newpartname//'.txt'}"_$filedate.txt; 
    done
```

```
ls dir2/
user_name1_1582067151.txt  user_name2_1582067158.txt  user_name3_1582067165.txt
```

You say that renaming takes a lot of time. But what a size of all your files? Do you know time of copying of all your files?