# List the size of each file in the current working directory

Tags: bash, scripts

I wanted to display the size of each file in the current working directory one at a time and I wrote this script

```
for $filename in "/etc/passwd";$filesize=$(stat --format=%s "$filename");echo $filesize.
```

But i am getting this error message

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `$filesize=$(stat --format=%s "$filename")'
```

Comment: I find plan old `ls -la` to be quite useful for this.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of errors in your script

1. variable assignment is `var=value` not `$var=value`
2. a `for` loop needs a `do` and a `done`

So

```
for filename in "/etc/passwd"; do 
  filesize=$(stat --format=%s "$filename");
  echo $filesize
done
```

But note that `"/etc/passwd"` is not "the current working directory" - it's a single file. If you really want to loop over files in the current directory, it would be

```
for filename in * . . .
```

Note that unless the number of files is very large, you could omit the loop altogether and just do

```
stat --format=%s *
```

Alternatively

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -printf '%s\n'
```

Comment: Also to list only files and not directories add `-tyoe f` like so `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%s\n'`

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using `ls` would be:

```
ls -l |

while read f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7 f8 f9
                do
                        echo "The size of $f9 is:"
                        echo "$f5"

                done
```

---

For extra information, please refer to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1205532/968501).

---

**Notice:**

In some cases [parsing the output of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) might be better avoided.